# Workbook_Open() code to change Application.ActivePrinter after Save As prompt fails

Tags: excel, vba

This code is supposed to change the printer, but only runs the Save As prompt. My users are busy farm laborers, so printer change must happen without their intervention.  Reason for this code is that Zebra label printer is used before this workbook, making view of this workbook a mess unless the printer is changed.  Cell B27 is in a table that automatically adjusts B27 result based upon the computer being used.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
    bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Application.ActivePrinter = Sheet3.Range("B27").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.SendKeys "{Escape}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
        
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error message and on what line, when you remove the `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: I would hazard to guess that the `on error resume next` clause is masking a `runtime error 1004: Method 'activeprinter' of object '_application' failed` error. This typcially pops up as a result of typos in the name of your printer. If this is the case, I suggest that you take a look into cell B27, and double check that it is functioning correctly

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Removing what turned out to be extraneous code (On Error..., Enable Events) led me to discover code that works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been able to find, the issue is that you need to include the port the printer uses in the active printer statement. Here is a link that will help:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/changing-the-active-printer-in-a-macro.1021932/

I ran a test to make sure using Microsoft Print to PDF as the printer. I put the code used to find the printer from the link in the module for the sheet ABOVE my VBA code (due to the Private Declares at the beginning). I put the function that does the actual finding of the printer on a button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ShowPrintersAndPorts
End Sub
```

What was returned was

"Microsoft Print to PDF on NE01:"

I put this in the cell you used and ran your code and everything worked perfectly. The main thing to note is that you must have the port on the end of the value coming from B27. You can do it through code once you know what the port is like so:

```
    Application.ActivePrinter = Sheet3.Range("B27").Value & " on NE01:"
```

Of course you must replace the NE01: with the port your printer is using. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much or your help.  Port is included in B27, but your thoughts helped me to figure out an approach that works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!!  Here's what works:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

```
Dim bFileSaveAs As Boolean
bFileSaveAs = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show

Application.ActivePrinter = Sheet3.Range("B27").Value
Application.SendKeys "{Escape}", True
Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView
```

End Sub