# Error 1004 assigning Application.ActivePrinter property

Tags: excel, vba

I receive the above error assigning a printer in an early bound instance of Excel from an Access DB. The `GetPrinterFullNames` function is common knowledge so I've put the code for it at the bottom of this post. The code I'm using is:

```
printerList = GetPrinterFullNames()

For x = 1 To UBound(printerList)
    For y = 1 To UBound(printerList, 2)
        If InStr(1, printerList(x, y), "XPS") > 0 Then
            m_xlApp.ActivePrinter = printerList(x, y)
            printerFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```

The required printer is correctly found in the array as

> Microsoft XPS Document Writer on Ne01:

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600856/workbook-open-code-to-change-application-activeprinter-after-save-as-prompt-fa) highlighting that the network needs to be included in the printer name, as it is included in my code this is not a duplicate. I've tried with and without the network in the string, still the same error. The `m_xlApp` was hidden, I've tried making it visible. I've verified that XPS is not already the active printer.

I've checked the active printer has the same string format

> Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:

Here's the code for `GetPrinterFullNames` which works fine.

```
Public Function GetPrinterFullNames() As Variant()
' Builds an array of installed system printers
Const PRINTER_KEY = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices" ' registry key in HCKU listing printers
Const HKCU As Long = &H80000001
Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1&

Dim ValueValue() As Byte, CommaPos&, ColonPos&, NameLen&
Dim prtIndex&, hKey&, RegResult&, printerNameLen&, DataType&
Dim printerNetID$, printerName$, Printers() As Variant, outArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
   
prtIndex = 0: printerNameLen = 255
printerName = String$(256, Chr(0))
ReDim ValueValue(0 To 999)
ReDim Printers(1 To 2, 1 To 20)  'Max of 20 printers displayed

RegResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKCU, PRINTER_KEY, 0&, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, hKey) ' open the printer list
RegResult = RegEnumValue(hKey, prtIndex, printerName, printerNameLen, 0&, DataType, ValueValue(0), 1000) ' first printer

Do Until RegResult = 259& '259& = Error: No more items
    NameLen = InStr(1, printerName, Chr(0))
    If NameLen > 1 Then printerName = Left(printerName, NameLen - 1)
    CommaPos = InStr(1, ValueValue, ",") ' find position of a comma and colon in the port name
    ColonPos = InStr(1, ValueValue, ":")
    On Error Resume Next
        printerNetID = Mid(ValueValue, CommaPos + 1, ColonPos - CommaPos)
    On Error GoTo 0
    prtIndex = prtIndex + 1
    Printers(1, prtIndex) = printerName & " on " & printerNetID
    Printers(2, prtIndex) = UCase(Printers(1, prtIndex)) 'For sorting
   
    printerName = String(255, Chr(0))
    printerNameLen = 255
    ReDim ValueValue(0 To 999)
    printerNetID = ""
    
    If prtIndex > UBound(Printers, 2) Then Exit Do
    RegResult = RegEnumValue(hKey, prtIndex, printerName, printerNameLen, 0&, DataType, ValueValue(0), 1000)
    If (RegResult <> 0) And (RegResult <> 234) Then Exit Do '234 = Error: No More Data
Loop

ReDim Preserve Printers(1 To 2, 1 To prtIndex)
ReDim outArray(1 To UBound(Printers, 2), 1 To 2)
For i = 1 To UBound(outArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(outArray, 2)
        outArray(i, j) = Printers(j, i)
    Next j
Next i
   
RegResult = RegCloseKey(hKey)
GetPrinterFullNames = outArray
    
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have any workbooks open in that instance at the time? If not, you can't set the printer.

Comment: @Rory Yes, that was the problem, thanks.